# React - Menu dropdown dynamic absolute position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am new to React and I am trying to translate my old website that was vanillaJS into ReactJS.

I have a button that should trigger a dropdown to open.

```
<button 
   type="button" 
   onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)} 
   ref={menuBtn}>menu</button>
```

and lower down in the DOM tree, I have:

```
{
isMenuOpen ?
  <nav style={{
     top: menuBtn.current.offset().top + menuBtn.current.outerHeight(),
     left: menuBtn.current.offset().left + (menuBtn.current.outerWidth() / 2)
  }}>
    ...
  </nav>
: null
            }
```

And

```
const [isMenuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
let menuBtn = React.createRef()
```

at the start of my `function` `Component`.

But it does not work.

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of null
```

Also, I think that even if this was working, it would not be responsive. If the user click on the button, then resize the window, it will not follow where the button is.

Thank you !

Comment: It seems like the ref menuBtn.current is empty. Are you using this code in a function component? Have you tried to change the React.createRef() to React.useRef()?

Comment: @JWGeertsma I tried createRef in a class and useRef in a function but neither work

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the use `.current.getBoundingClientRect()` instead of `.current.offset()`